# Get the value from Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark API calll like

```
substr($"fmt_num",(length($"mobile_num")).-(5), 4)
```

but it will throw an error like

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

How can I get the length of the `mobile_num` as integer to use as the start index of the `substring` function?

Comment: try implementing custom UDF

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.... but I found an easy way. There is a utility method substr in Column class with takes Column type as index positions

Comment: can you post answer what you did

Comment: refer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#cast(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is import `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` and you'd get a substring function that works with Column

Comment: Yes, but the index parameters needs to be integers. My requirement is to get the length of a column and use the length as the index parameter.

Comment: You also get a length that support columns https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html